# How to include relationship query In WHERE clause?

Tags: apex, soql

I have this query:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Account.Contacts) FROM Account
```

This would return something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "0015O000001W683QAC"
        Contacts: [{"Id": "0015O000001W612QQA"}]
    },
    {
        "Id": "0015O000001W683QAC"
        Contacts: null
    }
]
```

How do I include the Account.Contacts in the WHERE clause like:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Account.Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Account.Contacts != null
```

Comment: Hi Carl, Did you try using the query as below. `Select Id, Name,(SELECT Id FROM Account.Contacts) From Account Where id IN (Select AccountId From Contact)`

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use ANTI JOINS and is well documented in the official docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm).

**For Only Accounts with Contacts**

```
 SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts)
 FROM Account
 WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.